# Truecrypt + EXT2IFS/EXT2FSD Safe?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt, ext3

Is it safe to mount an EXT3 partition encrypted by Truecrypt in Windows using Truecrypt to decrypt it and then EXT2IFS or EXT2FSD to read/write to it?

I have not attempted it yet because I would rather not corrupt the partition.

**Edit:** 
I know it should work and be safe theoretically... What I want to know is has it been done without issues before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried EXT2IFS and it did not recognize the File-system I am assuming this is because the inode size was to large.

I then gave EXT2FDS a shot and I was able to read/write to the drive immediately after Truecrypt mounted it.

Everything seemed to work perfectly fine until I attempted to unmount the drive at which point the system BSODed. This tells me its not a good idea to continue using the drive in this manner. I am going to create a Linux VM to share the drive for now.

Comment: Please note this answer was created at 2011 and so it may changed a lot. Any one else wanted to try and report status of EXTFSD 0.48+?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by safe exactly, certainly Truecrypt can cope with EXT3 quite happily.

If you have an EXT3 partition encrypted by Truecrypt, then when you access that partition, Truecrypt will present you with the view of the filesystem that looks like EXT3. It handles the encrypt/decrypt on the fly, so you can treat it as if it were EXT3.

Comment: I have read about Truecrypt not working with EXT2IFS installed..This is suppose to be fixed but the fact that they conflicted at all has me nervous... so by safe I mean has it been done or have you done it yourself.

Comment: @jb48394 - I just stuck with EXT2IFS v1.10c until 1.11a came out - they both work fine. Of course you would want to take a backup anyway (standard operating procedure :-)